# How can i add a script with parameters?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I am trying to consume the google maps api in a metabox but i don´t know where to add the script provided by the api.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY></script>
```

This is my metabox:

```
<?php

function add_metabox_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('geocode_styles', CHILD_THEME_2020_URI . 'assets/css/geocode_metabox.css' );
    
    }
    
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_metabox_styles' ); 

function add_metabox_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('sf_geocode_scripts', CHILD_THEME_2020_URI . 'assets/js/geocode_metabox.js' );
    
    }
    
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_metabox_scripts' ); 



/*CREATE METABOX FOR GEOCODE*/    
function geocode_metabox() {

add_meta_box(

'sf_geocode_metabox',

'Geocode Locator',

'sf_display_geocode_metabox',

'park',

'normal',

'high'

);

}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'geocode_metabox' );

/*DISPLAY METABOX FIELDS*/

function display_geocode_metabox(){

    $html = '<div class="sf_form_group">';
    
    $html .= '<label for="sf_address">Address</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" id="sf_address" name="sf_address" value="" placeholder="Insert an Address" />';

    $html .= '</div>';

    $html .= '<div class="sf_lat_long">';
    $html .= '<div class="sf_form_group">';
    $html .= '<label for="sf_latitude">Latitude</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" id="sf_latitude" name="sf_latitude" value="" placeholder="Insert a Latitude" />';
    $html .= '</div>';

    $html .= '<div class="sf_form_group">';
    $html .= '<label for="sf_longitude">Longitude</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" id="sf_longitude" name="sf_longitude" value="" placeholder="Insert a Longitude" />';
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</div>';

    $html .= '<div class="sf_form_group">';
    $html .= '<label for="sf_geocode_map">Map</label>';
    $html .= '<div id="sf_geocode_map" name="sf_geocode_map"></div>';
    $html .= '</div>';

    echo html_entity_decode($html);

}
```

And this is my geocode_metabox.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    
    execute_js();


    function execute_js(){
        console.log("Hola mundo");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) from your PHP code to register and enqueue a script. Wordpress will then handle automatically adding the required script tags at the right place and you'll be able to instantiate and use the API from your javascript.

E.g. (untested, check the docs for your use case)

```
wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=KEY');
```

Comment: Use the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) action to enqueue the script only in the admin.